# Creating tool for Arcmap from script Updated

Tags: python, arcmap

I am attempting to create a tool for the first time from script for ArcMap but keep getting an error message when I run the script here is my code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


In_Buff_Feature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Out_Buff = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Buffer_Dist = arcpy.GetParameter(2)

arcpy.buffer_analysis(In_Buff_Feature, Out_Buff, Buffer_Dist,)
```

The error I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173\Week_3_Lab.py", line 31, in <module>
arcpy.buffer_analysis(In_Buff_Feature, Out_Buff, Buffer_Dist,)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'buffer_analysis'
```

Any feedback would be much appreciated!!
Thank You

Comment: Where are you running your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` function will read an input parameter from an ArcGIS tool.

During scripting and debugging, it is simplest to hard-code the function's input variables to verify that the function is working. Once the tool is (essentially) the way you want it, create the toolbox and script tool within ArcMap.

To accept input parameters from the tool execution dialog, you'll need to specify them when creating the script tool (and change the code to accept `GetParameterAsText` inputs). The best walkthrough for this is really the ArcGIS resource center.

- [Adding a script tool](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Adding_a_script_tool/00150000001r000000/)
- [Setting script tool parameters](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00150000000n000000.htm)

---

On a secondary note: The ArcPy functions are case-sensitive, so always check that you're spelling them correctly.

```
arcpy.buffer_analysis(In_Buff_Feature, Out_Buff, Buffer_Dist,) # wrong
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(In_Buff_Feature, Out_Buff, Buffer_Dist) # right
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I did have all three variables assigned and still get the error:    `in_layer_or_view = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
selection_type = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
where_clause = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)`

Comment: Posting complete code helps with troubleshooting. Can you edit your question to include that, and also a screenshot of the parameter setup of the tool in ArcMap?

Comment: I have updated the code and I apologize for not understanding exactly what your asking. The parameter setup of the tool in ArcMap, is that creating a new tool and defining the parameters in ArcMap?

Comment: Yes -- what the data types of the parameters are when you defined them in the tool setup. Sometimes I've had that be an issue when creating a tool. (I'm just trying to eliminate possible causes.)

Comment: I haven't set up the parameters, for that has been something I have been unable to do. Do I go through catalog and select new and then make a new toolbox

Comment: @M_2210 Essentially, yes. New toolbox, new script tool within toolbox, and then add the parameters. I've rewritten my answer to better answer your question :)